# Uploading a CSV to google sheets at the first blank row

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets

I am scraping a website data for each day and at the end of my program, the data is saved to a CSV and uploaded to a google sheet (using code I found here). Currently I have to hard code the rowIndex to be the first blank row, but my question is, how can I change the rowIndex to dynamically pull in the first blank row number in the google sheet?

```
    def push_csv_to_gsheet(csv_path, sheet_id):
    with open(csv_path, 'r') as csv_file:
        csvContents = csv_file.read()
    body = {
        'requests': [{
            'pasteData': {
                "coordinate": {
                    "sheetId": sheet_id,
                    "rowIndex": "5379",  # adapt this if you need different positioning
                    "columnIndex": "0", # adapt this if you need different positioning
                },
                "data": csvContents,
                "type": 'PASTE_NORMAL',
                "delimiter": ',',
            }
        }]
    }
    request = API.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body)
    response = request.execute()
    return response
# upload
with open(path_to_credentials, 'rb') as token:
    credentials = pickle.load(token)

API = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=credentials)
push_csv_to_gsheet(
    csv_path=path_to_csv,
    sheet_id=find_sheet_id_by_name(worksheet_name)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?hl=en) and **specify a column** as its `range` and set the `includeGridData` to **true** as [query parameters](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get?hl=en#query-parameters).

It will return a [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource:-spreadsheet) as a response body. You just need to count the number of `rowData` available in the response since it contains non-empty cell values in your specified range.

**[Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#resource:-spreadsheet) -> [sheets](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#Sheet) -> [data](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#GridData) -> [rowData](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#RowData)**

Once you get the number of non-empty rows, just **add 1 row offset** in your `batchUpdate()` request

---

### Example:

**Sheet:**

[image]

**Sample Request:**

[image]

- I want to select all column A in Sheet1, therefore I set the range to `Sheet1!A1:A`

**Sample Response:** (Some unnecessary data were removed)

```
{
  ....
  
  "sheets": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "sheetId": 0,
        "title": "Sheet1",
        "index": 0,
        "sheetType": "GRID",
        "gridProperties": {
          "rowCount": 1000,
          "columnCount": 26
        }
      },
      "data": [
        {
          "rowData": [
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "Date"
                  },
                  "effectiveValue": {
                    "stringValue": "Date"
                  },
                  "formattedValue": "Date",
                  .....
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            
            ....
            
            {
              "values": [
                {
                  "userEnteredValue": {
                    "stringValue": "22/01/2021"
                  },
                  "effectiveValue": {
                    "stringValue": "22/01/2021"
                  },
                  "formattedValue": "22/01/2021",
                  
                  ....
                  
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
 
        .....
  
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

}
```

Comment: Thanks! While I didnt do exactly this, it did put me on the track to what I needed.  I ended up adding this line to create the variable 'rows' 
rows = str(len(API.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, range=ranges).execute().get('values', [])))